# Remove or hide webpack in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular 2 project and I am using TypeScript.

I want to hide or remove webpack on developer tool. I read something about uglify but I didn't understand completely. There is an image. This is the [Chrome Developer tool screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5jOR.png) for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your application in AOT and prodcution mode by calling

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

in your project directory.

[See also](http://www.competa.com/blog/building-angular-4-application-production/)